# What happened to Java MVMs?

Tags: java, security, virtual-machine, isolation

These are Multitasking Virtual Machines with very nice, high level (i.e. language level) isolation between untrusting components. The information I could find about them all dates back to around 2006

- http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~gb/csc7700/Reading/OOPSLA01_p125-czajkowski.pdf
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mlam/archive/2006/11/multitasking_th_1.html

With lots of interest, but seems to have abruptly died there and then and nothing has been published ever since. What happened to them? Was there a single "we shall stop working on MVMs" decision, or did interest just wane and the projects die naturally?

Comment: They seem to have been a research project. It's more likely those fizzle out or that some of their ideas get applied in different contexts, than that they'd make it into the product stage as-is.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC sun lost a couple of DOD research contracts, so a few project were killed. Don't know if this was part of it.